# Python in command line not switching

Tags: python, command-line

Having installed python 2.7, and added python directory to PATH variable. I started windows command line and typed "python" + enter. It neither reports error nor switch to python command line. Instead just pop up python version info and revert to windows command prompt as below

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
    (c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    C:\Users\User>python
    Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500     64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

    C:\Users\User>
```

Restart computer does not help either. Just cannot find a similar case so post here.

Comment: you could debug the startup using `python -v` and post the output here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/5074858  . Just visit this link, it might help.

Comment: I tried python -v, the result seems normal, like import site # precompiled from C:\Python27\lib\site.pyc

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I tried that command, looks no error, outputs are like

Comment: put the path _before_ any other path. That would avoid conflicts with other DLLs in the path. Also can you paste the exact output of `python -v` command in your question? Also, maybe you could install previous 2.7.12 version to see if it helps.